# OnClickListener not working with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm cant get the `onclicklistener` to work with `fragments`. I've searched stackoverflow and tried all the tips but i still cant get it to work. So i do my first post here. 
I've tried adding **android:focusable="false", android:clickable="false"** and **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** to the layouts with no luck. Ive removed them because they make no difference. I've tried other solutions as well but none of them works. This is my first post so if i posted something wrong let me know and ill redo it, I've borrowed someones `customlist` just to get a working example. 

Here is one of the fragments i want a clickable list in

```
public class ActivitiesFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView list;

    String[] maintitle ={
            "Aktivitet 1","Aktivitet 2",
            "Aktivitet 3","Aktivitet 4",
            "Aktivitet 5",
    };

    String[] subtitle ={
            "A","B",
            "C","D",
            "E",
    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp,R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp,R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp,
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container,    false);

        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), maintitle, subtitle,imgid);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"One",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(position == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Two",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(position == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Three",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(position == 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Four",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(position == 4) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Five",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the Adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] maintitle;
    private final String[] subtitle;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] maintitle,String[] subtitle, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, maintitle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.maintitle=maintitle;
        this.subtitle=subtitle;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View rowView,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);


        TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView subtitleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

        titleText.setText(maintitle[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        subtitleText.setText(subtitle[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The xml for the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml for the list:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's whole implementation of `RecyclerView` with item click listener.

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ItemClickListener {

    RecyclerView rvList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        rvList = view.findViewById(R.id.rvList);

        ArrayList<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ItemData("Aktivitet 1","A",R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))
        list.add(new ItemData("Aktivitet 2","B",R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))
        list.add(new ItemData("Aktivitet 3","C",R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))
        list.add(new ItemData("Aktivitet 4","D",R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))
        list.add(new ItemData("Aktivitet 5","E",R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))

        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(this, list);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        rvList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(ItemData data, int position) {
        // item click will be listened here
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Fragment Layout: frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout for the list: item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView ViewHolder:

```
public class RecyclerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView titleText;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView subtitleText;

    public RecyclerVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        subtitleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
    }

    void bind(ItemData data) {
        titleText.setText(data.getMainTitle());
        imageView.setImageResource(data.getImgId());
        subtitleText.setText(data.getSubTitle());
    }
}
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerVH> {

    private ArrayList<ItemData> list;
    private ItemClickListener listener;

    public RVAdapter(ItemClickListener listener, ArrayList<ItemData> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerVH(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerVH holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(list.get(position));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClicked(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()),
                        holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}

interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(ItemData data, int position);
}
```

**Update 1:**

Add these lines to the root tag of item layout:

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:clickable="true"
```

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried it and no luck. I've also tried using RecyclerView from above, still no luck, nothing at all is clickable. I tried even to skip the list and just make a simple textview, not even that reacts when clicked on. It's like the onclicklistener never fires. Really wierd... In my MainActivity i'm using a bottomnavigationView with an onnavigationitemselectedlistener, im thinking maybe that is somehow taking over the whole application somehow... i'm out of ideas...

Comment: You were correct that the problem was with the focusable / clickable issue. The focus was somehow stuck in the mainactivity layout. After a smal change by removing a list there now i can add clicklisteners to any of the fragments. Thank you so much, ive been stuck for days.

Answer (score 1):

Time ago I had a similar problem, with an ImageView in my list item. My solution was changing `android:focusable` to false inside the ImageView block. I never knew why, but it worked fine.

Anyway, I strongly recommend to start using `RecyclerView` and `ViewHolder pattern`. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

It's much more powerful, flexible and a major enhancement over ListView.

Comment: I've tried it and no luck. I've also tried using RecyclerView from above, still no luck, nothing at all is clickable. I tried even to skip the list and just make a simple textview, not even that reacts when clicked on. It's like the onclicklistener never fires. Really wierd... In my MainActivity i'm using a bottomnavigationView with an onnavigationitemselectedlistener, im thinking maybe that is somehow taking over the whole application somehow... i'm out of ideas...